# I need some help understanding instances/references

Tags: java, class, variables, reference, instance

Just want to know if what I'm trying to teach myself is right.

I'll end up with something like this in one of my programs:

```
public class Test {
    int array[];

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test test = new Test();
        test.array = new int[10];
        test.fillArray();

        for(int i=0;i<test.array.length;i++)
            System.out.println(test.array[i]);
    }

    public void fillArray(){
        Test test = new Test();
        for(int i=0;i<test.array.length;i++)
            test.array[i]=i;
    }
}
```

But I get a null pointer exceptions. I seem to run into these types of issues a decent amount.. Would proper planning of my programs help with this?

The null Pointer was because when I say **new** it creates a separate object that only exists inside that method correct?

Are there any other ways to fix this other than making the array static or giving it a parameter (or is it argument..?) like I did below?

```
public class Test {
    int array[];

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test test = new Test();
        test.array = new int[10];
        test.fillArray(test.array);

        for(int i=0;i<test.array.length;i++)
            System.out.println(test.array[i]);
    }

    public void fillArray(int a[]){
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            a[i]=i;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to act on a parameter to fill the array of the test instance. You can simply refer to the class's field array in the fillArray method. Im assuming your goal is to populate the array field in your test instance created in main.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to populate the array field of the test instance I created in main(). How would I go about referring to the class's field array without it being static

Comment: See Elliots answer. Don't parameterize your fillArray method, refer to the class's field 'array' directly.

Comment: You should initialize your class members in constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first `fillArray` has a shadowing problem in that you are creating a new test instance and initializing it - instead initialize the field `array` within the current (or `this`) instance,

```
public void fillArray() {
  // Test test = new Test();
  for (int i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {
    this.array[i] = i; // <-- this.array or just array[i]
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe you mean `this.array[i] = i`.

Comment: Thanks, Why can you refer to class fields in a method but for main() it has to be static or have an instance of the class? Or should that be posted as a new question? (I'm just full of questions today...)

Comment: @Orion because `main` is static. That means it runs without a particular instance (or any instance) of the class.